# How to store 10KB+ data in a Solana Account?

Tags: anchor

I am trying to store 100KB+ data on a Solana Account. In Solana documents I've read that

> "The current maximum size of an account's data is 10 megabytes."

Source: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts

But when I try to create a space more than 10KB (space = 10240) it gives me error during init tests:

> "Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to reallocate account data"

Here is an example code:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space=100000)] 
     pub example_account: Account<'info, ExampleAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[account]
pub struct ExampleAccount {
    pub data: String,
}
```

I need to store 100KB data on that account. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the maximum account size is 10 megabytes, the maximum permitted size of a reallocation in an inner instruction is 10240 bytes. Anchor has to make a CPI to allocate the space for your account, so the maximum space it can allocate is 10240 bytes. If you want to store more than that, you will have to pass in an account you have created with a separate createAccount instruction.

If you are not initializing the account with a CPI, you would instead do:

```
#[account(zero)] 
 pub example_account: Account<'info, ExampleAccount>,
```

And then when you call Initialize:

```
const create_account_instruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: user,
    newAccountPubkey: exampleAccountKey,
    space: 100000,
    lamports,
    programId: yourProgramId
});
const your_instruction = program.instruction.initialize({ 
    accounts: { 
        exampleAccount: exampleAccountKey,
        user: user,
        systemProgram: systemProgramId
    }
});
const txn = new Transaction().add(create_account_instruction, your_instruction);
```

Comment: I am confused what does "you will have to pass in an account you have created with a separate createAccount instruction." means. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Are you familiar with the solana web3 SDK? I've elaborated in my example but you will probably have to be familiar with it to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Don't forget, there's a new realloc method which will allow you to increase by 10kb every transaction

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code and it works fine, I have created an account with space of 500,000 bytes. My idea is to store 10,000 public keys inside a vector on this account, but with 500K space I can only store 500 pubkeys which is strange because I thought pubkeys just needed 32 bytes, so to store I would need 10,000 * 32 = 320,000 bytes. What am i doing wrong? Ty.

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: Program logged: "Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory". And there are just 500 pubkeys in the vector, but the accout has 500KB of space, here's the address of the acc on devnet: 8q8rTUeW9Wn3seaYiCf7HU6bpimzQTt7zEDe3RgVteBc

Comment: You're probably running out of heap or stack space. While your account might have 500 kb of storage, your Solana program only has 4 kb of stack space and 32 kb of heap. To work around this limitation you'll probably want to use Anchor's zero-copy feature.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, this is new for me.. I couldn't find many documentation about zero_copy. I tried to implement it but got an error that says "the trait `Copy` may not be implemented" for the vector type.. My approach was the following:                    #[account(zero_copy)]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct PubkeysList {
    pub pubkeys: Vec<Pubkey>,
}

Comment: @EllieHigh When I hover on programId field it says: "Public key of the program to assign as the owner of the created account". On your example code, should I replace systemProgramId with my custom program Id? If not, why are we making system account owner of program? I am assuming if systemprogram owns that account, I won't be able to edit data inside it. Just like I can't edit my own SOL balance.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. For this you should definitely set the owner to be your program.

Comment: @user3688985 I'd suggest making another post for that question just so people can find the answer and I can write a more in depth explanation: Yeah, ZeroCopy is very finnicky. To use zero_copy your struct has to implement the Pod trait (https://docs.rs/bytemuck/1.10.0/bytemuck/trait.Pod.html). This is so you can map from struct access straight to byte access in the serialized account without deserializing the whole thing. I would suggest using a [Pubkey; N] (though you will have to manage the expandable array aspect yourself).

Comment: @EllieHigh You are right, I made a post for that question. Im still having problems getting the result I need. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-to-actually-store-10k-pubkeys-in-a-solana-account

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to allocate a PDA with up to 10 MiB. Use the init instruction to allocate 10240 bytes, this is the maximum that is allowed to be allocated through a CPI. Then you can execute another instruction that calls `AccountInfo::realloc` for every additional 10240 bytes that you need in the account. You can group many of these together in a single transaction. Ensure you have sufficient lamports in the account before reallocating.

The other approach, described in Ellen High's answer, is to initialize an account from a new keypair that signs a transaction containing a transaction-level instruction to the system program to initialize the account up to 10 MiB, plus an instruction that transfers ownership to the program (which can be tx-level or a CPI). But often it is preferable to use a PDA.